# Как получить данные из полей формы?

Tags: javascript, alert

Как получить данные из формы, чтобы они отображались в alert при нажатии на кнопку

```
<form class="js-form hidden" id="something">
    <div class="block-div">
        <p><b>Ваше имя:</b><br>
            <input type="text" name="name">
        </p>
        <p><b>Пол:</b><br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Мужской<Br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Женский<Br>
        </p>
        <p><b>Дата рождения:</b><br>
            <input type="date" name="date">
        </p>
        <p><b>Любимый цвет:</b><br>
            <select name="color">
                <option>Зеленый</option>
                <option>Красный</option>
                <option>Синий</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p><b>Согласен на обработку данных:</b>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
        </p><br>
        <input class="btn js-show-anketa" onclick="someFunc()" id="quantity" type="submit" value="Показать анкету">
    </div>

</form> 


<script>
    function someFunc(){
    alert(document.getElementById("something"));
    }
</script>
```

Буду очень благодарен

Comment: Проще всего через ```document.forms```

Comment: @IgorRudnev , вам зачем данные в alert? Если форму отправить - можно использовать `FormData` или `jquery serialize()`.

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров по заданию                                                                                            на форме располагается кнопка "показать анкету" - по нажатию происходит следующее:
1) показывается alert, в нем сообщение вида:
имя: %введенное_имя%
пол: %выбранный_пол%
дата рождения: %выбранная_дата%
любимый цвет: %выбранный_цвет%
согласие на обработку данных: %да_или_нет%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var form=document.getElementById('something');
form.addEventListener('submit',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = new FormData(this),
      result = 'Имя:'+data.get('name')+'; Пол: '+data.get('gender')+'; Дата рождения: '+data.get('date')+'; Любимый цвет: '+data.get('color')+'; Согласие на обработку данных: '+(data.get('checkbox')?'Да':'Нет');
   console.log(result);

})
```

```css
label,input,select{
  display:block;
}
p,label{
  margin:0 0 1em;
} 
[type=checkbox],
[type=radio]{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form class="js-form hidden" id="something">
 <label>
  <span>Ваше имя:</span>
  <input type="text" name="name">
 </label>
 <p>Пол:</p>
 <label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">
  <span>Мужской</span>
 </label>
 <label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">
  <span>Женский</span>
 </label>
 <label>
  <span>Дата рождения:</span>
  <input type="date" name="date">
 </label>
 <label>
  <span>Любимый цвет:</span>
  <select name="color">
   <option>Зеленый</option>
   <option>Красный</option>
   <option>Синий</option>
  </select>
 </label>
 <label>
  <span>Согласен на обработку данных:</span>
  <input id="agreement" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" >
 </label>
 <input class="btn js-show-anketa" id="quantity" type="submit" value="Показать анкету" >
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Создаем поле ввода

```
<input type="text"/>
```

Теперь нам нужно как-то сделать его уникальным. Чтобы по какому-то ключевому слову мы могли знать, что это, точно, оно... Хм...
А может так?

```
<input id="tratata" type="text"/>
```

Точно, мы можем дать ему идентификатор (id) для работы с ним.

Отлично.

Теперь пишем кусок скрипта

```
<script>
function getMeTratata(){

}
</script>
```

А как нам получить содержимое элемента? Может сохранить его в переменную? Хм..

```
<script>
function getMeTratata(){
   var variableContent;
}
</script>
```

Контент элемента мы можем получить с помощью знания Id и знания команды по управлению html.
В нашем случае :

```
document.getElementById('tratata');
```

Чтобы получить значение элемента мы можем обратиться к полю **value** нашей команды

```
document.getElementById('tratata').value
```

теперь когда нам удалось получить значение элемента мы можем положить его в переменную

```
<script>
function getMeTratata(){
   var variableContent = document.getElementById('tratata').value;
}
</script>
```

Через команду

alert();

мы можем отобразить полученную переменную

```
<script>
 function getMeTratata(){
   var variableContent = document.getElementById('tratata').value;
   alert(variableContent );
}
</script>
```

Чтобы вызвать функцию мы привяжем ее к кнопке

Весь код :

```
<input id="tratata" type="text"/>
<button onclick="getMeTratata()">click me</button>
<script>
 function getMeTratata(){
   var variableContent = document.getElementById('tratata').value;
   alert(variableContent);
}
</script>
```

Comment: а как отобразить в одном alert данные из нескольких полей input?

Comment: @IgorRudnev примерно так: ```... onclick="(function(){const f = document.forms[0]; alert([...Array(6).keys()].map(i => { return !f[i].value ? undefined : f[i].value; }))})();" ```